# Minecraft Server Status command not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've tried everything, nothing helped. The command after using it does not display anything. It says the command is not responding.

I've changed a few things but that didn't help either. I want to do it in app commands but it doesn't work.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
import urllib.request
import json
import os
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import threading
import requests

address = os.environ.get("ADDRESS")

class mcstatus(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  def server_status():
    
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/{address}")
    data = json.load(response)
    online = data['debug']['ping']

    if online:
        motd = data['motd']['clean'][0].strip()
        version = data['version']
        online_players = data['players']['online']
        max_players = data['players']['max']

        try:
            player_names = data['players']['list']
        except:
            player_names = "No players :("
          
        return motd, version, online_players, max_players, player_names
  
  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_ready(self):
      print("mcstatus.py is ready")

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message(self):

    command = message.content

    if command.startswith("status"):
        print("Executing command: {0}".format(command))

        try:
            motd, version, online_players, max_players, player_names = server_status()

        except Exception as e:
            await message.channel.send("Sorry, the server isn't up :(")
            print("Failed to find server: {0}".format(e))
            return

        if player_names == "No players :(":
            players = player_names
        else:
            players = ' '.join(str(e) for e in player_names)

        embed=discord.Embed(title="Server Status", description=f"Hi {message.author}, the server is up!", color=0x109319)

        embed.set_author(name="Minecraft Server", icon_url="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft/images/f/fe/GrassNew.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/340")

        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft/images/f/fe/GrassNew.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/340")
        
        embed.add_field(name="MOTD", value=motd, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Players", value=f"{online_players}/{max_players}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Online Players", value=players, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Version", value=version, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Address", value=address, inline=True)

        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%a %d %b %H:%M")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{current_time}")

        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

async def setup(client):
  await client.add_cog(mcstatus(client))
```

I don't understand this, help. I hope someone will help me. Thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

There should be nothing wrong with the code, but the command is probably not responding because the `server_status()` function is not async and it takes some time to fetch results from the web server.

A fix would be to use `interaction.response.defer()` to stop the interaction from expiring and wait for the results.

[API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=defer#discord.InteractionResponse.defer)